# Is it possible to make QList<QAbstractListModel>?

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

I have a custom C++ class, called CPage, which inherits of QAbstractListModel.

```
class CPage : public QAbstractListModel
```

In another class called CSession, I want to have a set of CPage. For this purpose, CSession have a private attribute called Q_PageSet:

```
QList<CPage*> Q_PageSet;
```

My problem is: when I try to do the following, my program crashes:

```
Q_PageSet.size() or Q_PageSet.count()
```

So my question is: Is that because I am not allowed to make a QList of QAbstractListModel ?

Thanks.

Comment: ***Is that because I am not allowed to make a QList of QAbstractListModel ?*** No. You have a bug somewhere in your code. Perhaps `this` is a nullptr.

Comment: @drescherjm say what?

Comment: @highvoltage379 no, you can have a list of pointers to anything.. or even to nothing. The problem probably lies elsewhere.

Comment: @drescherjm Yeah, I'm sorry but I am not quite sure I see what you mean.

Comment: ***I'm sorry but I am not quite sure I see what you mean*** Your bug is somewhere else in your code. Time to use your debugger to try to figure out where.